# Comparing 2 inputs in an if statement

Tags: python, function

I have written a if statement, but when I run this, I don't get the answers I want.. It returns me the "else" statement, even when I am giving the inputs right. Can someone help me figuring out what I have done wrong here?:

```
def classificatie():
    temperatuur = float(input("Vul hier de temperatuur in (in Kelvin): "))
    lichtkracht = float(input("Vul hier de lichtkracht in: "))

    if 5000 >= temperatuur <= 30000 and 0.000001 >= lichtkracht <= 0.01:
        print("De temperatuur en lichtkracht komen overeen met de temperatuur en lichtkracht van de Witte dwergen 2")
    elif 3000 >= temperatuur <= 5000 and 0.000001 >= lichtkracht <= 0.0001:
        print("De temperatuur en lichtkracht komen overeen met de temperatuur en lichtkracht van de Witte dwergen 1")
    elif 0 >= temperatuur <= 6000 and 10 >= lichtkracht <= 100:
        print("De temperatuur en lichtkracht komen overeen met de temperatuur en lichtkracht van de Reuzen")
    elif 0 >= temperatuur <= 7500 and 100 >= lichtkracht <= 1000:
        print("De temperatuur en lichtkracht komen overeen met de temperatuur en lichtkracht van de Heldere Reuzen")
    elif 0 >= temperatuur <= 30000 and 1000 >= lichtkracht <= 10000:
        print("De temperatuur en lichtkracht komen overeen met de temperatuur en lichtkracht van de Superreuzen (B)")
    elif 0 >= temperatuur <= 30000 and 10000 >= lichtkracht <= 100000:
        print("De temperatuur en lichtkracht komen overeen met de temperatuur en lichtkracht van de Superreuzen (A)")
    else:
        print("De temperatuur en lichtkracht komen overeen met de temperatuur en lichtkracht van de Hoofdreeks")

def main():
    classificatie()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: With what values have you tested and what is your output? What is the code supposed to do and could you translate the dutch (?) to English? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The following part of your code is incorrect:

```
if temperatuur > 2999 and < 30001 and if lichtkracht > 0 and <= 0.01
```

Replace it with:

```
if 2999< temperatuur < 30001 and 0< lichtkracht <= 0.01:
```

Comment: Thank you for the help loaTzimas, can you explain me why my code is incorrect? I don't see anything wrong with it ... :x

Comment: It's incorrect based on the syntax of if statement in Python

Comment: Hey loaTzimas, I have written the code I needed, but it doesn't work as I thought it would.. Can you help me out with this one? I don't get the mistake(s) I have made...

Comment: This is not correct:
`if 5000 >= temperatuur <= 30000` 
It sould be:   `if 5000 <= temperatuur <= 30000`  (first >= is wrong)